# Why libcurl doesn't decompress gzip automatically

Tags: curl, gzip, libcurl, compression

The basic test program is this:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://httpbin.org/gzip");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ACCEPT_ENCODING, "gzip");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, CurlWriteMemoryCallback); 
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void *)&output);
res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

Which is supposed to tell curl to do *gzip* decompression. It also uses the memory management function which is supposed to give me the "answer" in my output data area. But apparently curl is not decompressing and output contains *gzipped* data. How do I get it to do the right thing? And how will it? If curl is downloading on the fly into the memory callback (which reallocated memory as needed), how would curl rewrite the memory to leave it finally *ungzipped*?

Comment: Something odd with your libcurl build - like perhaps built without support for it? This command line works fine for me: `curl --compressed "http://httpbin.org/gzip" -v`

Comment: Sure. But that's a command line, with curl outputting to stdout. Not the libcurl library trying to keep the string data locally.

Comment: yes, but it uses libcurl so if curl can do it, it implies libcurl does it

Comment: This states that your code should work:

https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_ACCEPT_ENCODING.html

Comment: The issue may be on the server side? Did they send the `content-encoding: gzip` header correctly?